# Apache Qpid HTTP REST end points not working/responding

Tags: http, authentication, amqp, messagebroker, qpid

**Applicable to Qpid Java Broker: 0.32 onwards to 6.0.4**

Apache Qpid HTTP REST end points are not responding when requests are sent using following two ways even though correct authentication details( user name "admin" and password "admin") are provided.

- HTTP clients: RESTClient, RestEasy, HttpRequester (Firefox addons)
- Curl commands

Answer (score 3):

**Enable property "*Basic Authentication for HTTP enabled*" to allow HTTP REST invocations**

**Steps:**

1. Login to Broker Admin Console using browser - http://localhost:8080/ (use admin/admin if default authentication is not changed or appropriate login details)
2. Open ***Plugins > httpManagement***
3. Edit > Enable property "*Basic Authentication for HTTP enabled

**Screenshot**
[image]